# How to change Skype language to Portuguese in MacBook Pro running Mac OS X version 10.6.8?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, skype, language

I am unable to change the Skype language from English to Portuguese in MacBook Pro running Mac OS X version 10.6.8.

**What I have done:**

- I've downloaded the Portuguese version of Skype;
- I have under `OSX` → `System Preference` → `Language & Text` the language and country set to Portugal;
- I have my Skype account country and language set to Portugal, Portuguese.

Still the Skype application is using English and AFAIK no menu exists to change the application language within the application itself.

I was under the impression that Skype would collect the language from my system preferences as to properly present the menus.

How can I change the language to Portuguese then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a poke around and it looks like there are no language files for vanilla Portuguese included in Skype for OSX. You can check for yourself in the terminal:

```
ls /Applications/Skype.app/Contents/Resources/ | grep ^pt
```

This is also confirmed by the Skype website:
https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA176/which-languages-is-skype-for-mac-available-in

However, changing the system language to Portuguese (Brasil) **does** change the interface to Portuguese. So that could be a workaround if you could tolerate it.

If you don't want to change your system to Brazilian Portuguese, you can copy the language files to force Skype to use the Brazilian version when you are set to Portuguese Portuguese:

```
cp -r /Applications/Skype.app/Contents/Resources/pt_BR.lproj/ /Applications/Skype.app/Contents/Resources/pt.lproj
```